# Attention required One more step CAPTCHA

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, browser, websites, ubuntu-website

Why is this **Attention Required** One more step. Please complete the security check to access www.xyz.com" displaying whenever I'm accessing a website?
[image: problem]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to Ubuntu. Seems like you are using a proxy perhaps, which is requiring this, or some other problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using Tor? (The Onion Router, a way to anonymize your web browsing)

Many website owners use free DDOS protection services from CloudFlare. Since many automated website attacks (such as botnets) use Tor to anonymize and hide their identity, CloudFlare forces all Tor users to complete a security check before accessing websites that use their protection services. If this is the case, disabling Tor and connecting directly should remove the security checks.

Another possibility is that you live in an area of the world from which Cloudflare has noticed a high number of malicious attacks, and has put extra security in place for IP addresses linked to that geographical area.